# If the letters of the word 'mathematics' are arranged around a circle, what is the probability that alike letters are not together?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

If the letters of the word 'mathematics' are arranged around a circle, what is the probability that alike letters are not together?

My thought : I think that between two M, two A and two T, we can put the letters. But there are more cases when MTMT like arrangements are also possible. So please suggest a right way of counting.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion.  Instead count the number of arrangements where at least one of the letters that come in a pair *are* together.  To account for the circle aspect of arranging, go ahead and treat $S$ as **s**pecial and place it at the **s**tart, and just care about how things are placed with respect to the $S$.

Answer (score 5):

The word contains $\bf{2M,2A,2T,H,E,I,C,S}$

Place $\bf{S}$ as reference point, as suggested by JMoravitz. Then there are a total of $10$ letters left with $3$ pairs, and we can now treat them as permutable in a straight line with respect to $\bf{S}$

By inclusion-exclusion, we get

[Valid arrangements]
= [All ways]
$\,$- [at least $1$ pair together]
$\,$+ [at least $2$ pairs together]
$\,$- [all $3$ pairs together]

$= \dfrac{10!}{(2!)^3} - \dbinom31\dfrac{9!}{(2!)^2} +\dbinom32\dfrac{8!}{2!} - \dbinom33{7!} = 236880$